# hexadecimal value of opcodes

Tags: assembly, x86, hex, dos

I created a very simple assembly program that prints the letter 'a' in DOS. 
I opened it in a hex editor and the result was this:

Assembly code:

```
mov ah, 2 
mov dx, 'a' 
int 21h
```

Hex code

```
B4 02 B2 61 CD 21
```

I wanted to understand how it was generated! Like, I do not know if I'm right, but I realized that:

```
B4 = mov ah 
02 = 2 
B2 = mov dx 
61 = 'a' 
CD = int 
21h = 21
```

The `02`, `61` and `21` I understood what turned but and `B4`, `B2` and `CD`?

Comment: The official docs: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals If you are interested only in "instruction opcodes", the bytes into which different instructions are encoded then on the previously linked site start with this document: "Manual Volume 2A: Instruction Set Reference, A-M" The site linked by an answer below (http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html) is a very good summary/overview of the intel PDFs but read the intel docs to learn the exact behavior of instructions.

Comment: BTW, if you are thinking about playing around with assembly and maybe with disassembling/reverse engineering then try the best disassembler/debugger of all times, it has a free version (5.0) that knows much less then the newer versions but even this old free version can kick the ass of any other solution: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml It can come handy in analyzing stuff.

Comment: `B4 02 B2 61 CD 21` is a mixture of `opcode` `string` etc, so how can we tell if the hex code is `opcode` or `string`? etc I am confused, is there any indicators?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a nice reference: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html

As you can see:

- `CD` is the opcode for `int`
- `B0+reg` is the opcode for `mov reg, imm8`, where `reg` is the destination register and as you can see from [this table](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#modrm_byte_16), `ah = 100b` and `dx = 010b`

Comment: since there are 16 general purpose registers, it would require 4 bits to encode them.. isn't it?

Comment: in the reference you provided, they have given opcodes and equivalent hex values. But I am not understanding how to combine them to obtain valid instruction. For eg, 0x817 corresponds to cmp, and 0x5 corresponds to reg ebp. But with this information, how can I encode `cmp dword [ebp-4] 2`. I have searching through internet for this for around 2 hrs. Help me out!!

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB hi, how u solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Are Assembly x86 instructions:

- B4: mov ah mean move in the register ah
- B2: mov dx mean move in the register dx
- CD: int means software interrupt

I recommend you read this guide assembly x86 http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html